# Is there a way to pull out a template's parameter list to put into another metafunction?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

Say I have a `get_at` metafunction which gets the Nth type from a variadic template parameter list:

```
template <int I, typename ...Ts>
struct get_at;

template <int I, typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct get_at<I, T, Ts...> : public get_at<I-1, Ts...>
{
};

template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct get_at<0, T, Ts...> : public std::true_type
{
  typedef T type;
};

template <int I>
struct get_at<I> : public std::false_type
{
};
```

And I'd like to store the `Ts...` in a list type like so:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct list {};
```

How would I get the `Ts...` out of the containing `list` type so that I can put it into the `get_at` metafunction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to. Just write another metafunction (any problem can be solved by another layer of indirection?):

```
template <int I, typename Seq>
struct get_at_seq;

template <int I, typename... Ts>
struct get_at_seq<I, list<Ts...>>
: get_at<I, Ts...>
{ };
```

Or even:

```
template <int I, template <typename...> class C, typename... Ts>
struct get_at_seq<I, C<Ts...>>
: get_at<I, Ts...>
{ };
```

A note though, inheriting from `true_type` or `false_type` doesn't make sense for this use-case. You override `type`, but then you still have `operator bool()` on `get_at`, which makes no sense for this usage. Better to just write in `value` explicitly, e.g.:

```
template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct get_at<0, T, Ts...>
{
    typedef T type;
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean in your last comment.  Why does it not make sense?

Comment: @Adrian Does it make sense for your usage to do `bool has4 = get_at<4, Ts...>();`? I'd expect you're just using it for `::value` and `::type` - in which case just provide those.

Comment: I'm using it to determine if `I` has gone over the bounds of the list.  If `true_type` (value == `true`) the type was found.  If `false_type` (value == `false`) the type was not. Is there a reason why not to use that?

Comment: @Adrian I mean, still have `static constexpr bool value = false;` in that case. It may be just personal style choice. I prefer to reserve inheriting from `true_type` and `false_type` for those cases where I have a boolean metafunction or type trait.

Comment: Meh.  I don't see that it makes this any clearer or fuzzier.  BTW, is there any reason for using `constexpr` over `const` in this context?  They are equivalent in this context, correct?

Comment: I'll take your silence to mean yes.  Thanks.

Comment: So the answer is yes, in this context they are equivalent.  Thanks.